# Sense 4: How to add items to pull down menu?

Tags: htc-sense, notification-bar

I just received a HTC One S with Sense 4 installed. I've seen on other Android devices that the pull down menu contains different settings, such as a Wifi button.

[image]

Is there a way to add these buttons to the Sense 4 pulldown menu?

Comment: Use Widgetsoid from Play Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot check you image (corporate proxy forbids), but I take it you mean those "toggle buttons" to switch on/off things like Wifi, Bluetooth, etc. In this case, you can do so e.g. with [Elixier](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir) (first picture<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV0Zj.jpg)</sup>) or [Notification Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle) (second picture<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJNbE.jpg)</sup>)

[image: Elixier] [image: Notification Toggle]

Some Custom ROMs also come with something similar pre-installed, as e.g. [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) does.

Comment: I am unable to see left or right picture. Both are at bottom.

Comment: Here's the screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dZfVJ.jpg :)

Comment: Easy is your name... I am not Easy. Thanks for declaring me winner. Tell me if you want its party. BTW, I am using Mobile Web.

Comment: Are you really silent?

Comment: For chatting I use the chat :) Btw: Better now with the pics? I really forgot to keep the mobile apps/web in mind, thanks for reminding me. Will use above style for pics in the future.